# Выбор покупателя исходя из условия

Tags: mysql

Есть такая задача выбрать покупателей, у которых возраст от 10 до 50 лет?
Для решения задачи написал такой скрипт

```
SELECT pokupatel FROM humans WHERE date_rojdenia BETWEEN 10 and 50;
```

но проблема в том, что поле date_rojdenia хранит значения в unixtime и в тоге у меня выводится совсем не то, подскажите как решить проблему?

Comment: вычислить unixtime от 10 до 50 лет назад и задавать его

Comment: если я вас правильно понял, то скрипт получится что-то типо такого
`SELECT pokupatel FROM humans WHERE date_rojdenia BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_rojdenia )>10) and (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_rojdenia )>50);` или так нельзя?

Comment: Даже не близко. Во-первых, у вас хранится момент (дата рождения). а вас интересует возраст (настоящее время минус дата рождения). Во-вторых, таймштамп измеряется не в годах.

Comment: У вас в поле лежат секунды. А секунды сравнивать с годами нельзя. по хорошему даты над хранить в datetime формате а не в unixtime. Что то вроде `unix_timestamp(now()-interval 10 year)` придется использовать. И не забывайте, что в between сначала идет меньшее значение, а потом большее, а 50 лет назад это меньше, чем 10 лет назад

Comment: А еще "50 лет назад" - это 1968 год. А unixtime считается с 1 января 1970 года, так что вы в таком поле физически не можете хранить даты рождения 50 летних ...

Comment: @Mike Отрицательным числом можно.

Comment: @PeterOlson Положить то можно. только вот никакие функции конвертации времени в MySQL не способны дать отрицательный unixtime. И кстати, если ваш ответ заработал у ТС, значит у него время все таки лежит в каком то нормальном виде. В случае если оно в виде int означающего unixtime то ваше решение с ним не работает даже на положительных числах. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1e05d/1

Comment: @Mike вы правы, в таком виде работать не будет((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 лет назад:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 YEAR)
```

50 лет назад:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 50 YEAR)
```

Получается так:

```
SELECT pokupatel FROM humans WHERE date_rojdenia 
   BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 50 YEAR) 
       and DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 YEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему с временной меткой решил так, может кому-нибудь пригодится

```
SELECT pokupatel FROM humans WHERE date_rojdenia 
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 50 YEAR) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 YEAR);
```